# Not able to create a servlet inside a maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, maven

I have created a maven project using --  maven-archetype-webapp in Eclipse IDE.

I was able to create and execute the index.jsp, but now I need to create a new servlet. But when I right click the project and select a new servlet (New->Other->Web->Servlet) I cannot see my maven project in the dropdown, hence I cannot create the servlet using the Eclipse IDE in my Maven project.

Can some one point out why this is happening. I am new to Maven.

Thank You,

Edit - My web.xml

```
 <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
 <web-app>
   <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>  
 </web-app>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IF you are not able to create servlet from the menu. 
Check the following.

1. Check if Web.xml file is created by maven in the WEB-INF folder.
   If not create it.
2. Is the project shown as a Web Project Or Not?
   Right Click On
   Project->Properties->Project Facets-> Check if Dynamic Web Module is
   selected or not.?
   Select it for making the project as a web project.

Comment: I have web.xml . But I am not able to get Eclipse to create a new Servlet because it is not showing my project in the dropdown.

Comment: I am able to create a new servlet if I select a non maven project.

Comment: No I directly created a maven project from using Eclipse IDE File->New->Other->Maven->Maven Project

Comment: I have added my web.xml to the post

Comment: Did you select war as the packaging ?is your project shown as a web project?or normal java project ?

Comment: My pom.xml has the statement -- <packaging>war</packaging> . It is a web app as I used maven-archetype-webapp.

Comment: Right click on project->properties->Project Facets. check if Dynamic Web Module is selected or not .

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I selected Dynamic Web Project. But now I have two web.xmls . One in src->main->webapp->WEB-INF->Web.xml and other is in WebContent->WEB-INF->web.xml . Which one should I delete and which one should I use?

Comment: keep both ,its okey.both are the same file only but shown differently.

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phl3f.png)
1.here create a folder named java.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGP9J.png)
2.after creation of folder you will see this like src/main/java.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9AsP.png)
3.in that src/main/java create a package in that package create a servlet